# How to design background image and header have same background image in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

check this image for example

[image]

please answer the question in vuetify only

Comment: Please show your effort and share some code to help!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the css background property.

```
{
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/510/300?random);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover
 }
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/yLNEvem